# UIView not resizing within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has two elements. A UIView and a UILabel. The cell is used for voting so I want to be able change the dimensions fo the UIView based on the vote. I currently am setting the frame of the UIView in the cellForIndexAtPath method. The frame of the UIView is being changed correcting (as I am checking in 3 places to make sure using NSLogs) but is not being reflected on the cell after they are displayed on the screen.  Does anyone know why the UIView's frame would say it has changed but when displayed it would stay at the cell's frame size?

### EDIT

```
NSLog(@"before: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.voting_scale.frame));
[cell.voting_scale setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, row_dim.height+10.0)];
[cell.voting_scale setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, row_dim.height+10.0)];
[cell.voting_scale setClipsToBounds:true];
NSLog(@"after: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.voting_scale.frame));
```

Hope this helps more

Comment: are you calling setNeedsDisplay on the cell after making the change?

Comment: i wasn't but just tried and it did not change anything. thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: have you tried setting the bounds rectangle as well?

Comment: yeah I had tried that as well. I set the frame and the bounds and it still takes up the whole cell. I have edited the question to show the code I am running

Comment: and then [cell.voting_scale setNeedsUpdate] ?

Comment: just added that in as `[cell.voting_scale setNeedsDisplay]` but that still does not force it update the view.

Comment: not an answer, but want to mention that naming your variables/properties like so: votingScale, rowDim, would be in line with Objective-C naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a thorough understanding of the behind-the-scenes processes of UITableView but I have found that when my UITableViewCell subclasses don't seem to be working as intended, that moving as much of the code as I can to the layoutSubviews method of the subclass instead of calling it in cellForRowAtIndexPath of the UITableViewController helps.

Comment: yeah I wasn't able to get the functionality exactly how I wanted it but thanks for the tip. I will have to try this next time. I ended up making a view adding it as a subview to the cell and then removing by tag every time I build a new cell.